# Cannot synthesize property 'testjj' with incomplete type 'void'

Tags: ios, objective-c

Why I cant use property on void function under header `@interface` ?

```
@property (nonatomic) void testjj;
```

-in m file:

```
-(void)testjj{
  
  NSLog(@"testjtestj");
  
}
```

- 

```
Cannot synthesize property 'testjj' with incomplete type 'void'
```

Comment: ```void``` does not make sense for an ivar (or even a variable). It has no size so how must it be stored at all. Only a function can be void meaning it does not return anything, but you can not have a nothing variable.

Comment: but don't trick yourself.. `@property (nonatomic) void *testjj;` is possible - which is a pointer declaration (but not the only possible one).

Comment: Yes yes yes - ```void *``` or void pointer is a wonderful thing. It (typically) points to a region of allocated memory that you can use for anything. Here the void portion is very powerful as you are not constrained to e.g. a pointer to ints or to chars or to objects. So you have this generalised region of memory and you can e.g. write a function to save that to disk and restore it later. Here it makes so much sense as you'd probably use the same code wether it is int or char or objects or whatever and void * gives you the freedom to do such a general thing. But void alone - not so much ...

Comment: Just think about it - suppose you do have a void variable. What will its value be? Will you be able to change it and if so, to what? If you print it, what will it print? None of these makes any sense. Void really is a moniker that means nothing or anything at the same time. If used on its own it means nothing. A function that returns nothing is a void function. A function that takes no arguments takes void arguments. Void pointer means it points to anything. A void pointer can be a pointer to int or float or char or objects. So void also has this duplicity about it.

Answer (score 0):

The comments deal with declaring a void *variable* as an ivar. The comments also elaborate a bit on the difference between void and void pointer. This is important.

It seems you want to have an ivar that is, in fact, a void *function*. That is of course possible, if you make use of void pointer and not void, as shown below.

```
// A few functions for later
void f1( int a, int b )
{
    NSLog(@"f1");
}

void f2( int a, int b )
{
    NSLog(@"f2");
}

void F1( void )
{
    NSLog(@"F1");
}

void F2( void )
{
    NSLog(@"F2");
}

// Typedef makes life easy
typedef void ( func )( int a, int b );
typedef void ( Func )( void );

// Some class
@interface MyClass : NSObject

// Defining ivars ...

// Typedef is easier
@property (nonatomic) func * ma;
@property (nonatomic) Func * mb;

// Direct is also possible
@property (nonatomic) void ( * na )( int, int );
@property (nonatomic) void ( * nb )( void );

@end

@implementation MyClass

// Assigning the ivars
- ( void ) setIt
{
    self.ma = f1;
    self.mb = F1;

    self.na = f2;
    self.nb = F2;
}

// 'Using' the ivars
- ( void ) doIt
{
    self.ma ( 1, 2 );
    self.mb ();

    self.na ( 1, 2 );
    self.nb ();
}

// Have some fun
- ( void ) swapIt
{
    func * t1 = self.ma;
    Func * t2 = self.mb;

    self.ma = self.na;
    self.mb = self.nb;

    self.na = t1;
    self.nb = t2;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

in .h

```
- (void)testjj;
```

in .m

```
self.testjj;
```

That is OK.